# iphone calendar sample

Tags: iphone, calendar

I would like to have an iphone application...... I want to be able to have some sort of calendar where you can select any day and fill information (and save it under that date) I understand I need databases but I'm not sure how can I do this? Plan is to use the date as a primary key but I'm kind of confused in how getting this to work? any pointers? thank you

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone SDK allows you to use SQLite as a database; that gives you a fairly powerful database that should be more than enough for the application you are describing.

[This link](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/) will take you to a fairly decent tutorial on adding a SQLite database to an iPhone application.